# How Would You Convert this WPF to Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

Help me Convert this WPF to Silverlight

I am interested in a Charles Petzold C# example that shows how to do a fisheye effect ( http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/05/Realizing-a-Fisheye-Effect-in-Silverlight.html ).  The XAML code samples are in WPF but I want to try this in Silverlight.

When I try to create the XAML code in Silverlight, the compiler complains in two locations:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
Error   1   The type 'x:Type' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

<Style.Triggers>
Error   2   The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'Style'.
```

How do I convert this to Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `x:Type` in Silverlight, doesn't support that markup extension. Just use `<Style TargetType="Button">`. As far as triggers, you can use them directly in the control xaml, not in style.

```
<Button>
    <Button.Triggers>

    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, with `Button` being in scope, you would do,

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
```

But in the second case, [`Triggers`](http://microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) isn't (fully) supported by Silverlight, so you would likely need to implement anything that happens there within the appropriate event handlers (in code).

Comment: Triggers are supported in Silverlight, just not on Style. The only trigger that is not supported is DataTrigger.